# Mavericks OS X Server Software Updates: "Duplicate" entries? How do they differ?

Tags: macos, software-update, server.app

I'm running OS X Server on Mavericks with software updates service. In the list of updates there are several duplicate entries:

[image: Updates list]

For instance there are two safari entries. Looking at the details, I can see that they have the product ids 031-02224 and 031-02225. Similar entries exist for iTunes updates etc.

What are the differences between such duplicate entries?

How do I find out more details for those product ids?

(Google comes up with a bunch of telephone numbers :-) )

Comment: It's probably Safari for different builds / versions of OS X. Apple hides the details of drivers, differing builds of the same software from end users, but on the server you do get to peek behind the details of how software update actually works. I haven't opened those two files yet, but I see there's an answer explaining how to if you care...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're different versions of the software (Safari v6.1.4 in this case) that the client computer will choose between based on... well, something. The info about what the differences are (and which is needed for which clients) is all in computer-readable format, not really human-readable.

You can download the two packages, then search under /Library/Software Update/Data/html/content/downloads for them. And I do mean search -- the 031-02224 is in .../downloads/17/37/031-02224/8gxq9vhxcra3e5adif9fhvafxoefypqvlx. Spotlight will find the folders by the package ID, but only if you search in the relevant parent folder (if you do a general search, it omits them because they're considered "system files", not the sorts of things normal users would be interested in).

Once you've found the relevant folder read through the various files (especially the .pkm and .dist files), you'll find that 031-02224 is the version for Lion, and 031-02225 is the version for Mountain Lion.

So... it's possible to find out, but not easy (and far from user-friendly).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that clears things up a bit. Being a Mac newbie I thought, that I might have missed some obvious part which tells me the details, but it is as it is :-)